# Uncaught OAuthException: (#10) To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I submitted a facebook app review for taggable_friends. But facebook not approving taggable_friends for my app.

Facebook keep on saying that i have following error in my app.

> "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#10) To use taggable_friends
>   on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your
>   app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by
>   Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our
>   documentation on reviewable features:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review thrown in
>   /home/casrtoramar/public_html/wetstyles.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/template-parts/fb-api/inc/base_facebook.php
>   on line 1249".

I am getting the above error, when i am logged-in as normal user, but not getting the above error, when i am logged in as admin/developer/tester.

MY Facebook App Site URL:

> http://www.wetstyles.com

Please help me, to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Well first of all you might want to properly _catch_ exceptions in your code, instead of letting them result in fatal errors.

Comment: Hi CBroe, can you please help to catch exceptions in my code, since i am new to facebook api. please help me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the FB API, but is a PHP thing. If you are unfamiliar with the concept, then start here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php Pretty sure the examples in the SDK documentation should also take care of catching exceptions for the most part, so check those as well.

Comment: CBroe, thanks for your help. Will check and get back to you, if i need any further assistance.

Comment: Hi CBroe, I have implemented catch exceptions in my code, can you please check from your end via my app URL: http://www.wetstyles.com with your FB login and let me know your confirmation to submit my app for facebook approval.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to developers.facebook.com and add your app to that. 
If you just want to test it(testing purpose) assign role admin, tester or developer to yourself on facebook developer API.

Then you will be able to see your app name listed in the upper left drop-down of `Graph API Explorer`

then hit `me/taggable_friends` on `Graph API Explorer` or through your app,  You will be able to see the list of all your friends on facebook.

For normal users, You need to get `feature review` for `taggable_friends` from facebook that you need to fill one form on your facebook developer account.